# Correct syntax of vmkfstools command

Tags: virtual-machine, esxi

I am trying to create a virtual disk:

```
vmkfstools –c 100G –d eagerzeroedthick –a lsilogic xyz.vmdk
```

I tried to execute this command inside xyz folder of data center (on a ESXI server).
It keeps raising error and shows me help:

```
"Extra arguments at the end of the command line."
```

Any idea, what am I doing wrong? Is there any alternative to vmkfstools tool that I can use?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the "–" characters which are not ASCII dashes (decimal 45):

```
 $ printf "%d\n" "'-"
 45
```

This may happen when you copy commands from e.g. a blog post.